# How to invoke custom element member method on click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component

AKA How to get around or avoid `Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed` when accessing custom element methods.

So I'm using David Shapiro's small library [angular-custom-element](https://github.com/dgs700/angular-custom-element) to experiment with features such as custom elements to future proof our components. I've gotten pretty far, they seem to register. however, in the example, it tries to show invoking a element's member function inside `ng-click` in the directive example.

```
 template: '<div ng-click="el.elementMethod()">{{ el.propertyNameOne }} CUSTEM ELEMENT CLICK ME</div>',
```

Below is the full code and runnable snippet. It does not throw the error until you click on the 'CUSTEM ELEMENT'

I tried adding a 'return true' in the method to get around the security as suggested by other posts but to no avail. Is there perhaps an alternate implementation?

```js
angular.module('appy', []);

angular.module('appy.elementDirectives', ['customElements']);

var app = angular.module('appy', [
    'appy',
    'appy.elementDirectives'
]);



app.config( function($customElementsProvider ) {
        'use strict';           
        var definitions =  [
                {
                  name: 'shiny-button',
                  definition: {
                    parent: HTMLButtonElement,
                    properties: {
    
                        propertyNameOne: {
                            get: function () {
                                // do any value calculations
                                var valueVar = 'testFooValue';
                                return valueVar;
                            },
                            set: function (val) {
                                // do any value calculations
                                val = val + 'X';
                                return val;
                            },
                            attribute: {
                                name: 'property-one'
                            }
                        },
                        propertyNameTwo: {
    
                            attribute: {},
                            value: 'hello',
                            readOnly: true
                        },
                        booleanProperty: {
                            attribute: {
                                name: 'bool-prop',
                                // note that "true" here just signifies that the attr should
                                // treated as a boolean,
                                boolean: true // default is false
                            },
                            value: true // default is false
                        }
                    },
    
                    // In all callbacks "this" referes to the element instance
                    callbacks: {
                        created: function () {
                          console.log('created')
                          
                        },
    
                        // is called when the element is inserted into the DOM
                        attached: function () {
                            console.log('attached')
                        },
    
                        // is called when the element is removed from the DOM
                        detached: function () {
                            // include any cleanup logic
                            console.log('detached')
                        },
    
                        // called upon any attribute change including attr set programatically
                        // during element instantiation (but not if the elem already exists in markup)
                        attributeChanged: function (attr, oldVal, newVal) {
                            console.log('attributeChanged', attr, oldVal, newVal)
                        }
                    },
                    members: {
    
                        elementMethod: function (args) {
                            alert("member click");
                            console.log('clicked member');
                            return true;
                        },
    
    
                        memberNameOne: {
                            get: function (val) {
                                return val;
                            },
                            set: function (val) {
                                val = val + 'X';
                                return val;
                            },
                            value: 'blah blah',
                            readOnly: true
                      }
                    } 
                }
            }];

        console.log("Register Element");
        //$customElementsProvider.register( 'shiny-button', definitions[0].definition );
        $customElementsProvider.registerCollection(definitions);
});

 

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  var that = this;
  
  $scope.showTest = true;
  
   $scope.testButtonClick = function(){
      alert("testButton click")
    }
  
});

app.directive('shinyButton', function($customElements) {
  return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope: {
                nothingHereYet: '=propertyNameOne'
            },
            replace: false,
            template: '<div ng-click="el.elementMethod()">{{ el.propertyNameOne }} CUSTEM ELEMENT CLICK ME</div>',
           
            controllerAs:'shinyCtrl',
            
            // 3.4 at a minimum inject $scope and $element into your controller
                    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $document, $log){

                        // 4. This is the only line of code that is required.
                        // this command takes care of binding all custom properties
                        // to the $scope including triggering a $digest() when
                        // any custom property is changed outside of Angular
                        // After this line you can enjoy the full power of AngularJS
                        // when interacting with your Custom Element
                        $customElements.$watchElement($scope, $element);

                        $document.on('member:changed', function(evt){
                            if(evt.detail.propName == 'a protopype prop we need to watch'){
                                // i.e. $scope.el.__proto__.memberNameOne
                                $scope.$digest();
                            }
                        });

                        // 4.2
                        // bind to an event on the element
                        // since all prop changes generate a change event
                        // other frameworks in the page can import and react
                        // to the same component
                        $element.on('prop:changed', function(evt){
                            $log.log(evt.detail); 
                            $scope.$emit(evt.detail);
                        });
                        
                        
                        

                        // 4.3
                        // gets the original custom elem config obj mostly for any debug
                        var info = $customElements.info($element);

                        //$customElements.$importElement($scope, $element, ['array','of','property','names']);

                    },
                    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
                        // ...
                    }
            
        };
});





/*! (C) WebReflection Mit Style License */

/*
 * AngularCustomElement
 * https://github.com/dgs700/angular-custom-element

 * Version: 0.2.0 - 2014-11-01
 * License: MIT
 */
 
 
 
 /* Requires a Custom Element polyfill for all browsers other than Chrome
 Recommended:  https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element */
/*! (C) WebReflection Mit Style License */
(function(e,t,n,r){"use strict";function q(e,t){for(var n=0,r=e.length;n<r;n++)J(e[n],t)}function R(e){for(var t=0,n=e.length,r;t<n;t++)r=e[t],$(r,c[z(r)])}function U(e){return function(t){g.call(L,t)&&(J(t,e),q(t.querySelectorAll(h),e))}}function z(e){var t=e.getAttribute("is");return d.call(l,t?t.toUpperCase():e.nodeName)}function W(e){var t=e.currentTarget,n=e.attrChange,r=e.prevValue,i=e.newValue;t.attributeChangedCallback&&e.attrName!=="style"&&t.attributeChangedCallback(e.attrName,n===e.ADDITION?null:r,n===e.REMOVAL?null:i)}function X(e){var t=U(e);return function(e){t(e.target)}}function V(e,t){var n=this;O.call(n,e,t),B.call(n,{target:n})}function $(e,t){N(e,t),I?I.observe(e,_):(H&&(e.setAttribute=V,e[i]=F(e),e.addEventListener(u,B)),e.addEventListener(o,W)),e.createdCallback&&(e.created=!0,e.createdCallback(),e.created=!1)}function J(e,t){var n,r=z(e),i="attached",s="detached";-1<r&&(C(e,c[r]),r=0,t===i&&!e[i]?(e[s]=!1,e[i]=!0,r=1):t===s&&!e[s]&&(e[i]=!1,e[s]=!0,r=1),r&&(n=e[t+"Callback"])&&n.call(e))}if(r in t)return;var i="__"+r+(Math.random()*1e5>>0),s="extends",o="DOMAttrModified",u="DOMSubtreeModified",a=/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+$/,f=["ANNOTATION-XML","COLOR-PROFILE","FONT-FACE","FONT-FACE-SRC","FONT-FACE-URI","FONT-FACE-FORMAT","FONT-FACE-NAME","MISSING-GLYPH"],l=[],c=[],h="",p=t.documentElement,d=l.indexOf||function(e){for(var t=this.length;t--&&this[t]!==e;);return t},v=n.prototype,m=v.hasOwnProperty,g=v.isPrototypeOf,y=n.defineProperty,b=n.getOwnPropertyDescriptor,w=n.getOwnPropertyNames,E=n.getPrototypeOf,S=n.setPrototypeOf,x=!!n.__proto__,T=n.create||function K(e){return e?(K.prototype=e,new K):this},N=S||(x?function(e,t){return e.__proto__=t,e}:w&&b?function(){function e(e,t){for(var n,r=w(t),i=0,s=r.length;i<s;i++)n=r[i],m.call(e,n)||y(e,n,b(t,n))}return function(t,n){do e(t,n);while(n=E(n));return t}}():function(e,t){for(var n in t)e[n]=t[n];return e}),C=S||x?function(e,t){g.call(t,e)||$(e,t)}:function(e,t){e[i]||(e[i]=n(!0),$(e,t))},k=e.MutationObserver||e.WebKitMutationObserver,L=(e.HTMLElement||e.Element||e.Node).prototype,A=L.cloneNode,O=L.setAttribute,M=t.createElement,_=k&&{attributes:!0,characterData:!0,attributeOldValue:!0},D=k||function(e){H=!1,p.removeEventListener(o,D)},P=!1,H=!0,B,j,F,I;k||(p.addEventListener(o,D),p.setAttribute(i,1),p.removeAttribute(i),H&&(B=function(e){var t=this,n,r,s;if(t===e.target){n=t[i],t[i]=r=F(t);for(s in r){if(!(s in n))return j(0,t,s,n[s],r[s],"ADDITION");if(r[s]!==n[s])return j(1,t,s,n[s],r[s],"MODIFICATION")}for(s in n)if(!(s in r))return j(2,t,s,n[s],r[s],"REMOVAL")}},j=function(e,t,n,r,i,s){var o={attrChange:e,currentTarget:t,attrName:n,prevValue:r,newValue:i};o[s]=e,W(o)},F=function(e){for(var t,n,r={},i=e.attributes,s=0,o=i.length;s<o;s++)t=i[s],n=t.name,n!=="setAttribute"&&(r[n]=t.value);return r})),t[r]=function(n,r){y=n.toUpperCase(),P||(P=!0,k?(I=function(e,t){function n(e,t){for(var n=0,r=e.length;n<r;t(e[n++]));}return new k(function(r){for(var i,s,o=0,u=r.length;o<u;o++)i=r[o],i.type==="childList"?(n(i.addedNodes,e),n(i.removedNodes,t)):(s=i.target,s.attributeChangedCallback&&i.attributeName!=="style"&&s.attributeChangedCallback(i.attributeName,i.oldValue,s.getAttribute(i.attributeName)))})}(U("attached"),U("detached")),I.observe(t,{childList:!0,subtree:!0})):(t.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",X("attached")),t.addEventListener("DOMNodeRemoved",X("detached"))),t.addEventListener("readystatechange",function(e){q(t.querySelectorAll(h),"attached")}),t.createElement=function(e,n){var r,i=M.apply(t,arguments);return n&&i.setAttribute("is",e=n.toLowerCase()),r=d.call(l,e.toUpperCase()),-1<r&&$(i,c[r]),i},L.cloneNode=function(e){var t=A.call(this,!!e),n=z(t);return-1<n&&$(t,c[n]),e&&R(t.querySelectorAll(h)),t});if(-1<d.call(l,y))throw new Error("A "+n+" type is already registered");if(!a.test(y)||-1<d.call(f,y))throw new Error("The type "+n+" is invalid");var i=function(){return t.createElement(p,u&&y)},o=r||v,u=m.call(o,s),p=u?r[s]:y,g=l.push(y)-1,y;return h=h.concat(h.length?",":"",u?p+'[is="'+n.toLowerCase()+'"]':p),i.prototype=c[g]=m.call(o,"prototype")?o.prototype:T(L),q(t.querySelectorAll(h),"attached"),i}})(window,document,Object,"registerElement");
/*
 * AngularCustomElement
 * https://github.com/dgs700/angular-custom-element

 * Version: 0.2.0 - 2014-11-01
 * License: MIT
 */
!function(){"use strict";function a(){function a(a,b){function c(a){var b=parseFloat(a);return!isNaN(b)&&isFinite(b)?b:a}function e(a,b,c,d,e,f){if(!c)return b;c.setterCalled[e]=!0;try{e&&f?b?c.setAttribute(e,""):c.removeAttribute(e):e&&c.setAttribute(e,b),c.onPropChange(b)}catch(g){}return d=f?!!c[a]:c[a],c.propChangeNotify(c,a,b,d,e,"prop:changed"),b}if("string"!=typeof a||!/.*-.*/.test(a))return console.error("Invalid element name: ",a),this;if(a=a.toLowerCase(),d[a])return this;var f=b.parent?b.parent.prototype:b["extends"]?Object.create(document.createElement(b["extends"]).constructor).prototype:HTMLElement.prototype,g=b["extends"]||null,h=b.properties||{},i=b.members||{},j={prototype:{}},k=function(){};for(var l in i)!function(a,b){function c(a,b,c){return document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("member:changed",{detail:{propName:c,newValue:a,oldValue:b||null}})),a}var d,e,f,g,h,i,l=this;"function"==typeof b[a]?j.prototype[a]={enumerable:!0,value:b[a]}:(d=b[a],i=d.readOnly||!1,g=d.value||null,e="function"==typeof d.get?function(){return g=d.get.call(l,g)}:function(){return g},f=i?k:"function"==typeof d.set?function(b){b=d.set.call(l,b),h=this[a]||null,g=c(b,h,a)}:function(b){h=this[a]||null,g=c(b,h,a)},j.prototype[a]={get:e,set:f,enumerable:!0})}(l,i);j.prototype.registerCallback={value:function(a,b){a.onPropChange=b},enumerable:!0},j.prototype.propChangeNotify={value:function(a,b,c,d,e,f){a.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(f,{detail:{propName:b,newValue:c,oldValue:d,attrName:e||null}}))},enumerable:!0},j.prototype.definition={value:b};var m,n=b.callbacks||{},o=n.created||k,p=n.attached||k,q=n.detached||k,r=n.attributeChanged||k,s={},t=[];for(m in h)!function(a,b){t.push(function(d){var f,g,h,i,l,m,n,o,p;o=!1,l=null,g=null,f=b[a],n=f.readOnly||!1,p=f.attribute?!0:!1,o=p&&f.attribute.boolean?!0:!1,p&&!n&&d?(g=f.attribute.name?f.attribute.name:a.toLowerCase(),s[g]={name:a,bool:o},o?l=d.hasAttribute(g)?!0:f.value?!0:!1:(l=d.hasAttribute(g)?d.getAttribute(g):f.value?f.value:null,l=c(l)),d.hasAttribute(g)||(o&&l?d.setAttribute(g,""):o?d.removeAttribute(g):d.setAttribute(g,l)),d.setterCalled[g]=!1):o&&!d?l=f.value?!0:!1:(l=f.value?f.value:null,l=c(l)),h="function"==typeof f.get?f.get:function(){return l},i=n?k:"function"==typeof f.set?function(b){b=f.set.call(d,b),b=e(a,b,d,m,g,o),l=b}:function(b){l=e(a,b,d,m,g,o)},d?Object.defineProperty(d,a,{get:h,set:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0}):j.prototype[a]={get:h,set:i,enumerable:!0}})}(m,h),t.forEach(function(a){a.call(this,null)});j.prototype.createdCallback={enumerable:!0,value:function(){this.setterCalled={};var a=this;t.forEach(function(b){b.call(a,a)});var b=o?o.apply(this,arguments):null;return b}},j.prototype.attributeChangedCallback={enumerable:!0,value:function(a,b,d){if(s[a]&&!this.setterCalled[a]){var e=s[a];e.bool&&""===d&&(d=!0),this.setterCalled[a]=!1,this[e.name]=e.bool?!!d:c(d)}var f=r?r.apply(this,arguments):null;return f}},j.prototype.attachedCallback={enumerable:!0,value:function(){this.classList.remove("unresolved");var a=p?p.apply(this,arguments):null;return a}},j.prototype.detachedCallback={enumerable:!0,value:function(){var a=q?q.apply(this,arguments):null;return a}};var u={prototype:Object.create(f,j.prototype)};return g&&(u["extends"]=g),d[a]=document.registerElement(a,u),this}function b(a){return Array.isArray(a)?(a.forEach(function(a){var b=a.name,c=a.definition;return"string"!=typeof b||c!==Object(c)?(console.warn("bad element definition format"),!1):void e.register(b,c)}),!0):(console.error("parameter to registerCollection must be an array"),!1)}function c(){return{info:function(a){return a[0].__proto__.definition},$watchElement:function(a,b,c){c=c||!1,a.el=b[0],c||a.el.registerCallback(a.el,function(){return setTimeout(function(){a.$digest()},0),!0})},$importElement:function(a,b,c,d){var e=null,f=null;return Array.isArray(c)&&(c.forEach(function(a,b,c){c[b]=c[b].toLowerCase()}),e=new MutationObserver(function(b){b.forEach(function(b){-1!==c.indexOf(b.attributeName)&&a.$digest()})}).observe(b[0],{attributes:!0,childList:!0,characterData:!0,attributeOldValue:!0})),d&&(f=b.addEventListener(d,function(){a.$digest()})),Array.isArray(c)&&d?{observer:e,eventBinding:f}:!1}}}var d={};window.registeredElements=this.registeredElements=d,this.register=a;var e=this;this.registerCollection=b,this.$get=c,c.$inject=["$window"]}angular.module("customElements",["ng"]).provider("$customElements",a)}(window);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appy">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
  <script  src="angular-custom-element.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

<shiny-button>this will be replaced by directive template</shiny-button>

<br/><br/>

<div ng-show="showTest" ng-click="testButtonClick()">Test Click Div</div>


</html>
```

Comment: can you post the link to your plunker?

Comment: You should be able to click, "run code snippet" button above these comments to execute the code. If you really want to see a plunker version, I do happen to have one. http://plnkr.co/edit/BzX6OI?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because AngularJS 1.x is not yet web component friendly.  It assumes that you must be stupid if you reference DOM properties directly from w/in the angular universe since that code could be malicious or it just violates the original notion that angular code should be completely encapsulated from the outside world and the framework handles all outside interaction.  While this is true in most cases, it came about at a time before we knew that Custom Elements would soon be core to the way we construct reusable UI web components.

Until NG 2.0 you'll probably need to do something like this:

replace this:

```
<div ng-click="el.elementMethod()">
```

with this:

```
<div ng-click="callMember()">

$scope.callMember = function(){
    $scope.el.elementMethod();
};
```

With the replacement code there is no error.

What's interesting though, is that the same DOM access via `{{ el.propertyNameOne }}` does not cause Angular to throw the same error. Go figure.