# How to append a custom directive and make it execute in the DOM on user click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement something in which I want to add elements to DOM on button click. Previously I implemented it using jquery and it worked fine however I was unable to pass data from front-end to back-end. So I created a custom directive which I am trying to add using button click event, but it is not getting appended. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .directive('myDirective',myDirective);

        myDirective.$inject =['$compile'];

        function myDirective($compile) {

            var directive = {
                templateUrl :"addSteps.templ.html"
            };
            return directive;

        }

})();
```

Code to append directive(element) into DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#addDiv').click(function () {
            console.log('step added');
            $('#add').append($compile("<my-Directive></my-Directive>")(scope));   
            scope.$apply();
       })
});
```

Comment: Wrap the code in `scope.$apply()` instead of calling it at last.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke custom element member method on click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554992/how-to-invoke-custom-element-member-method-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because you are adding an Angular directive to the DOM via a jQuery context.  Angular has no idea that it is supposed to render this.  My advice to you would be to create an array of items in your controller, use `ng-click` on the button to add an item to the array and then use the directive `ng-repeat` on that array to generate new iterations of your directive like so:

```
<button ng-click="arr.push(1);">Click Me</button>
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in arr"></my-directive>
```

This will add a new instance of `my-directive` to your view every time you click the button.  This is because the model manipulation is occurring within an Angular context, so it adds it to the $digest cycle and basically keeps an eye on it to change.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with CraigR that its not working as you are adding an Angular directive to the DOM via a jQuery context.

You can add element via angular directive and achieve the same result as follow -
Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/FbFxwYIkEyp82d0MV7J3?p=preview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("addButton", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<button add-message>Click to Hello Message</button>"
  }
});

myApp.directive("addMessage", function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("click", function() {
      angular.element(document.getElementById('append-data')).append($compile("<div><my-directive></my-directive></div>")(scope));
    });
  };
});

myApp.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<h3>Hello</h3>"
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <add-button></add-button>
    <div id="append-data"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help. I figured out the solution,

//function to append elements into DOM

```
    function addDiv() {
        var element = angular.element(document.createElement('my-Directive'));
        var el = $compile(element)($scope);
        //where to place the element
        angular.element($('#add')).append(element);
        $scope.insertHere = el;
        var objName = 'step'+number;
        var id = 'id'+number;
        dataCtrl.id =id;
        console.log(objName);
        number++;
    };
```